# encodeURIComponent in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react function returning a promise from axios, and I need to encode an equation type string is being passed to it.

```
const { equation } = this.state;
axios.post(`${this.state.rootUrl}/integrate`, { equation }).then(some other code)
```

I want to encode the string equation before passing it to the API for a query.

I have tried the following but it didn't work.

```
axios.post(`${this.state.rootUrl}/integrate`, { encodeURIComponent(equation) })
```

I also tried this:

```
const { equation } = this.state;
const { test } = encodeURIComponent(equation);
axios.post(`${this.state.rootUrl}/integrate`, { test }).then(some other code)
```

This also didn't work.

Here's the full code of the function where I'm trying use this:

```
handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { equation } = this.state;
    // const { test } = encodeURIComponent(equation);
    axios.post(`${this.state.rootUrl}/integrate`, { equation })
      .then((response) => {
        const data = response.data;
        this.setState({ data: data });
        console.log(equation);
        if (data != null) {
          this.setState({input: data.response[0]});
        }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your original example, you're using the shorthand syntax for setting object properties - the following two lines of code are equivalent:

```
{ equation }
{ equation: equation }
```

Your second two examples don't do the same thing! In example two, you're trying to use the shorthand with a method call, which won't work. In example three, you're trying to destructure the return value of `encodeURIComponent(equation)`, which *also* won't work (it returns a string).

Fawaz's first example almost works, but there's a subtle difference in behavior - because they've named the variable `test`, the key of the object being passed to Axios will *also* be `test`. Remember, these are equivalent:

```
{ test }
{ test: test }
```

Presumably, your API is expecting something called `equation`, not `test`, so this won't work.

To get the right behavior, you should make sure the object you're passing has the right key:

```
const test = encodeURIComponent(equation);
axios.post(`${this.state.rootUrl}/integrate`, { equation: test })

// or

axios.post(`${this.state.rootUrl}/integrate`, { equation: encodeURIComponent(equation) })
```

Answer (score 1):

There seems an issue in using the shorthand. Try like this :

```
const test = encodeURIComponent(equation); // no braces here
axios.post(`${this.state.rootUrl}/integrate`, { test }).then(some other code)
```

or

```
axios.post(`${this.state.rootUrl}/integrate`, { test: encodeURIComponent(equation) })
```